# Data won't pass to View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on an LMS. I want to pass data from the database to the view via the controller.

This is a sample of the controller code. I have (Dump And Die) but nothing shows in the collection instance.

[image]

```
class UserController extends Controller
        {
            public function setting($step = 1)`enter code here`
            {
                $user = auth()->user();`enter code here`
                $userMetas = $user->userMetas;

            if (!empty($userMetas)) {
            foreach ($userMetas as $meta) {
                $user->{$meta->name} = $meta->value;
            }

        $data = [
                'pageTitle' => trans('panel.settings'),
                'user' => $user,
                'certificate' => $userMetas->where('name', 'certificate_additional'),
                ];

                dd($data);

        }
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that that userMeta has a name equal to `certificate_additional`? What do you get if you `dd($userMetas)`?

Comment: Also, you're possibly missing a `->get()` at the end of this: `$userMetas->where('name', 'certificate_additional')` (unless `$userMetas` is a Collection, then yeah, anyber's comment is likely correct, or a great place to start debugging this)